# counting values and group them without empty values

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can i merge the values without including '0' values.

```
SELECT DATE_PART('YEAR', BIRTHDATE), SUM(CASE WHEN GENDER  = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) MAN,
SUM(CASE WHEN GENDER = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as FEMALE FROM TABLE
GROUP BY 1
```

My output

```
YEAR   MAN   FEMALE
1970   2      0
1970   0      5
1971   3      0
1971   0      2
```

Desired output

```
YEAR   MAN  FEMALE
1970    2    5
1971    3    2
```

I have tried it with another counting from MAN and FEMALE, but that doesnt work.

Comment: I find it hard to believe your query returns the specified output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should work, although I would recommend writing it as:

```
SELECT DATE_PART('YEAR', BIRTHDATE) as year,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE GENDER  = 'M') as MAN,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE GENDER  = 'F') as FEMALE
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY year;
```

Your results suggest that you are really using something like:

```
GROUP BY 1, gender
```

Comment: you are totaly right, that was the problem. I thought its not a big problem, if i have my gender included(didnt wrote it in my example above)

Answer (score 0):

simply you need to correct your **Group By** syntaxe,

```
Group By DATE_PART('YEAR', BIRTHDATE)
```